# Postgresql xmlconcat slow

Tags: xml, performance, postgresql, plpgsql

I got a problem with a PL/PGsql stored procedure outputting an xml.

Basically, the function, output as xml the result of a query.

Query is fast enough but i observed the xmlconcat became slower and slower when the set of result became too big.

This is a simplified content of the function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function (v_limit int)
    RETURNS xml AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    v_rec record;
    v_xml xml;
    v_query text;
BEGIN

    v_query := 'SELECT * FROM test_table LIMIT ' || v_limit;

    FOR v_rec IN EXECUTE v_query LOOP

        v_xml := xmlconcat(v_xml,
                     xmlelement(name content, v_rec.content)
                 );

    END LOOP;

    RETURN v_xml ;
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER ;
```

The table test_table contains just a field named content of type text. The average length of content is 100 chars.

The problem appears with a large amount of records to concat.

Look at this explain analyzes. The time needed increase exponentially.

```
db=# explain analyze select test_function(500);
                                      QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=42.890..42.893 rows=1 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 42.909 ms
(2 rows)


db=# explain analyze select test_function(1000);
                                       QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=109.153..109.159 rows=1 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 109.178 ms
(2 rows)

db=# explain analyze select test_function(10000);
                                        QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=0.00..0.26 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=8304.257..8304.277 rows=1 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 8304.298 ms
(2 rows)
```

The cost of the single query, without xmlconcat, is just 36ms for 10000 records.

Any suggestion about improve the efficiency of xmlconcat?

**Server version is 8.3.6... so i got no xmlagg function available**

Comment: Have you tried `xmlagg(expression)`? Details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this kind of memory problems quite often with XML. This is often associated with the use of a DOMparser. The DOMparser keeps the complete document in memory, which is very handy when you want to process the document intensively.

Another reason might be that old objects are not cleaned up properly. That was sometimes also the cause of decreasing performance as the parsing of a document creates a lot of temporary objects.

XMLconcat might parse each time all the parameters. If only one of above mentioned problems do exist while processing the code, then will the processing get slower and slower.

It is impossible to understand what causes those problems exactly other then delving into the code of xmlconcat - Peter Eisentraut might know, I guess. But the only thing you need is to concatenate a set of xmlelements. Using xmlconcat might be over the top, because it is much too complex for a probably predictable situation. I would suggest you stop using xmlconcat and start writing the concatenation yourself. Might be the fastest and most proper solution at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

postgresql 11 has a same poor perfomance of xmlagg, but it's easely can be replaced with string_agg. Some tests:

```
select xmlagg(xmlelement(name "id", s.id)) el
from generate_series(1, 10000) s(id)
- Execution Time: 131.849 ms

select xmlagg(xmlelement(name "id", s.id)) el
from generate_series(1, 20000) s(id)
- Execution Time: 623.741 ms

select xmlagg(xmlelement(name "id", s.id)) el
from generate_series(1, 30000) s(id)
- Execution Time: 1571.545 ms

select string_agg(xmlelement(name "id", s.id)::text, '')::xml el
from generate_series(1, 10000) s(id)
- Execution Time: 38.743 ms

select string_agg(xmlelement(name "id", s.id)::text, '')::xml el
from generate_series(1, 20000) s(id)
- Execution Time: 54.399 ms

select string_agg(xmlelement(name "id", s.id)::text, '')::xml el
from generate_series(1, 30000) s(id)
- Execution Time: 91.766 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function (v_limit int)
    RETURNS xml AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN SELECT xmlagg(xmlelement(name content, tt.content))
           FROM test_table tt 
           LIMIT v_limit;
END
$BODY$
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER ;
```

Comment: i'm sorry... i forgot to specify i'm using Postgre 8.3.6... no xmlagg available